# Wrapping nside td is not working in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I have a script that writes a value from a `form` to a `<td>`, like so:

```
var num_rows = 1;
$(".add_menu_item").click(function() {
var value1 = $('#dealer_type').val();
if (value1.length) {
    if (num_rows == 1) {
        $('.dealer_contact_list').find('tr:last').after('<tr>').append(
        $("<td id='type'></td>").text(value1),
    } else {
        $('#type').attr('rowspan', num_rows + 1);
    }
}
num_rows++;
});
```

Now I want to write the value in an input field but still wrap it in a `<td>`. I have tried to do it like so, but can't get it to work. Any ideas?

```
$("<input>").val(value1).wrap("<td id='type'></td>"),
```

Comment: Your code is syntactically invalid. Is that your real code?

Comment: Something's wrong with that first code sample -- the block just after `if (num_rows==1)` doesn't parse.

Comment: Yea... how is that first block of code supposed to work?

Comment: Hi, here is the full code on jsfiddle, without the wrap(). http://jsfiddle.net/clintongreen/XYkcx/12/ I just tried to put the basic code here. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could possibly try:

```
$('<td>').attr('id','type').append($('<input>').attr('type','text').val(value1));
```

That should give you a `td` with an text `input` inside it.